# I need to add console/info level and file/debug level handlers in this function

Tags: python, logging

I need help with logger handlers. I need to add console handler on info level and file handler on debug level in this function and I can not do it.

```py
def create_logger() -> logging.Logger:
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename=RESOURCES / 'ass_3.log',
        format='%(asctime)s | %(name)s | %(levelname)-5s | %(message)s',
        datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        filemode='w',
        level=logging.DEBUG)


    return logging.getLogger('ass_3_logger')
```

Comment: `basicConfig` isn't something you should be calling in a function that returns a specific logger. It should be called *once*, at the beginning of a *script*, to configure the root logger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just import logger and load a logger.config like this:

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig(fname='file.conf', 
disable_existing_loggers=False)

# Get the logger specified in the file
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.debug('This is a debug message')
```

and as logger config use something like this:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,sampleLogger

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=sampleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_sampleLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=sampleLogger
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=sampleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_sampleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```